# Spark Scala: How to pass column name in UDF with DataFrame.Select

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a code snippet like this:

```
case class Purchase(cid: Int, pid: String, num: String)

val x = sc.parallelize(Array(
  Purchase(123, "234", "1"),
  Purchase(123, "247", "2"),
  Purchase(189, "254", "3"),
  Purchase(187, "299", "4")
))

// I have a dataframe structure: [cid: int, pid: string, num: string] 
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(x)

// Defining a column name which I need to transform. Its value can change, like pid
val colName = "num"

// Defining a UDF. The definition of the UDF can change
val toIntUdf = udf((myString: String) => myString.toInt )

// This works
df.select( toIntUdf($"num") ).collect
```

I am looking for a way to avoid using "num". Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by `its value can change, like pid`?  When does it change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean you want to use `colName` instead of using the literal `$"num"`, here's how:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(toIntUdf(col(colName))).collect
```

Comment: What if I have a List[String] consisting of column names and I want to pass them all to a udf ?

Answer (score 1):

You could select your column this way. You can find further documentation in [Spark's DataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)

```scala
df.select(toIntUdf(df(colName)))
```

or alternatively:

```scala
df.select(toIntUdf(df.col(colName)))
```